# Transfer "Criminal Case" game from OLD tablet to NEW one

Tags: applications, data-transfer

I have the game/app Criminal Case on my Tablet (Nvidia Shield). I recently got a NEW tablet (also an Nvidia Shield) and want to copy the game over to my new tablet (transferring over my game progress). I downloaded a new copy of the game onto my new tablet, but I need to transfer over my game progress somehow. The game does not require an internet connection, so I assume all of my game progress is saved somewhere on my tablet ... I just don't know where.

I've tried contacting the game's developer, but they have not responded to any of my questions.

Note: The game allows you to login through Facebook, and I assume that I could transfer the game over that way ... however, I never connected to Facebook via my tablet (nor do I want to). So, I'm looking for an alternative solution (where are the files saved on my tablet, and what needs to be copied over).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the package name of the game in your internal memory>Android>Data folder.

Possibly copy the entire folder that matches the package name of that game to your new device (same location, same name).

I don't know about the game, but that's a possible location where the data maybe stored.

EDIT.

I installed the game just to check where it's files are, they are in your devices' `/data/data/com.prettysimple.criminalcaseandroid` folder

And to access that folder you need root access, so unless your device is rooted, the game data cannot be transfered by copying and pasting files, if there's some other way that game offers to sync data I don't know about it.

Comment: Tried that. I didn't see any folder relating to the game. And, I didnt have that many games/apps on my old tablet.  So, I could see which folders related to which apps and there were no folders that made me say, "hmm, I don't know what app that relates to ... maybe it goes with Criminal Case".  So, are there hidden folders that I might not be able to see, or are they stored elsewhere?

Comment: How do you get "root access"?  I don't see a data/ folder on my device. I see an Android/data/ folder  ... but that's it.

Comment: You have to root your device...please visit XDA forums to know how to root...but beware, rooting your device...means your phone's warranty would be null and void.

Comment: I don't mind rooting my old device ... but I'm not sure that I want to with my new device. I assume that I'd have to root my old device to pull the files, and then root my new device in order to add the files.  Correct?

Comment: Yes.. You are correct...both devices need to be rooted